# Spatial join by argument closest, but based on majority of vertices

Tags: pyqgis, line, qgis-3, spatial-join

I'm often working with different polyline datasets which represent street networks. One of the most common tasks I have is to join information from one layer to another. Often there are no mutual attributes to utilize.

Geometries between layers are similar, but they're far from identical. First thought would be to use spatial join based on argument *closest*. Alongside the fact that the argument doesn't exist in core QGIS function, as far as I know it is based on a single, closest vertex. Since we're talking about wide road networks, the single, closest vertex might not be the correct one (see image). It's more about two lines sharing approximately the same path.

In the image, based on approximate paths of the three lines shown, the orange line should be joined with the blue one. Yet, since a vertex of the green line is the closest to any of the vertices of the orange line, the join would actually happen between them.

So I reckon the solution should take into account all of the vertices, get their closest counterpart and do a join based on their majority.

My question is: are there any existing open source tools or combination of them that could tackle this efficiently or should I start planning a script?

I'm using QGIS 3.4 on Windows.

[image]

Comment: One practical, quick and dirty solution might be to buffer the counterpart layer and then do spatial join based on a _within_ / _contains_ argument, though that's not exactly what I'm looking for here.

Comment: Looking for the very same. Must be possible?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/163759)

Comment: Maybe you can flag each road as closest to Horizontal or Vertical. This might help join the appropriate feature.

Comment: @klewis Do you have a proposal how to deduce vertical or horizontal orientation for roads in your given context? On another note, I've learned that QGIS 3.8 will finally have spatial join by argument closest, but it is unclear if it will contain an option to execute it by majority or average of vertices.

Comment: @Ville, You can compute a simple line angle using the end-points. An angle between 45 and 135 or between 225 and 315 is flagged as Vertical, otherwise the Line is closest to Horizontal. Not accurate for L shaped lines, but maybe good enough for the majority of your lines.

Comment: @klewis That's not a bad idea, but I'm afraid the road networks in question will be too complex by their trajectories in order for that (end points at least) to work. On the other hand complex trajectories are going to be an issue with overall closeness of vertices as well now that I think about it. Some kind of extra step is probably needed.